# How to reduce top margin with newlfm?

Tags: newlfm

I am using a standard letter from `newlfm`. I already adjusted it a bit to my needs (not in the below example code), but I cannot figure out how to reduce the space to the top (between the address and the top of the document). I tried `\newlfmP{headermarginsize=0in}` but it still seems to be too far down. Is it possible to shift the whole text a bit more up? I also tried something with `geometry` package, but it didn't seem to have an effect either.

```
 %\title{...}
 %
 %
 \documentclass[11pt,stdletter,orderfromtodate,sigleft]{newlfm}
 \usepackage{blindtext, xfrac}

 \newlfmP{sigsize=10pt} 

 \PhrPhone{Phone} 
 \PhrEmail{Email} 

 \newlfmP{Headlinewd=0pt,Footlinewd=0pt}

 \namefrom{...} 

 \addrfrom{
 Insert address
 }

\phonefrom{insert phone}

\emailfrom{insert email} 

\dateset{insert date}% Date


\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}


\textbf{Subject}: text text text text text text text text text \\
\vspace{3mm}

Dear Sir or Madam,\\

blaaa


\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually a more important question: how do i remove/reduce white space in general in newlfm? I would for example like to reduce the space above "Dear Sir or Madam.." but I cannot figure out how

Answer (score 2):

To adjust vertical whitespace in `newlfm` there are various commands. See the table at the end of this post.

For your specific need, I think the commands

```
 \newlfmP{dateskipbefore=-1cm}
 \newlfmP{dateskipafter=0cm}
```

will "reduce the space to the top (between the address and the top of the document)" as you request. Note how negative numbers can be used to reduce the space. For more information on `newlfm`, see [LaTeX’s alternative letter class newlfm](https://texblog.org/2013/11/11/latexs-alternative-letter-class-newlfm/)

[image]